# IF statement: how to leave cell blank if condition is false ("" does not work)

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I would like to write an IF statement, where the cell is left blank if the condition is FALSE.
Note that, if the following formula is entered in C1 (**for which the condition is false**) for example:

```
 =IF(A1=1,B1,"")
```

and if C1 is tested for being blank or not using `=ISBLANK(C1)`, this would return `FALSE`, even if C1 seems to be blank. This means that the `=IF(A1=1,B1,"")` formula does not technically leave the cells blank if the condition is not met.

Any thoughts as to a way of achieving that? Thanks,

Comment: That's because it's not blank. It has a formula in it. Try this =C1="" or if you want to get really crazy =IF(OR(C1="",ISBLANK(C1)),TRUE,FALSE)

Comment: @Stepan1010 No need to get *that* crazy because `OR(C1="",ISBLANK(C1))` is equivalent.

Comment: Here is a way to get a true empty blank if condition is met: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39351425/1903793

Comment: @Museful, they aren't strictly equivalent. `C1=""` will work for both scenarios, but `ISBLANK(C1)` will return false if `C1` contains a `""` from an IF formula. Your response made it sound like you could use either one in any situation.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try this instead

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C1),TRUE,(TRIM(C1)=""))
```

This will return true for cells that are either truly blank, or contain nothing but white space.

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452597/excel-blank-empty-cell) for a few other options.

***edit***

To reflect the comments and what you ended up doing:  Instead of evaluating to "" enter another value such as 'deleteme' and then search for 'deleteme' instead of blanks.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C1),TRUE,(TRIM(C1)="deleteme"))
```

Comment: Well, the problem for me is not the results of the "blank test" per say, but rather the following: I apply the `if statement` to a whole row, and then I would like to use `Go To -> Special -> Blanks` to delete the blank cells from the row, i.e. the cells for which the condition was false. However, the `Go to` doesn't detect any blank cells in my row, specifically due to this problem that my IF statement doesn't return blank cells per-say. Therefore, I need to alter my IF statement so that it appropriately returns blank cells.

Comment: If your going to delete them anyways, can you return a different value (i.e. 'deleteme') and then search for that value in your other routine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That is precisely what I did! I tried = IF(A1,B1, NA()), and I used `Go To -> Special -> Formula -> Errors` and I successfully deleted the cells that don't satisfy the condition! Thanks for the tip again!

Answer (score 80):

Unfortunately, there is no formula way to result in a truly blank cell, `""` is the best formulas can offer.

I dislike ISBLANK because it will not see cells that only have `""` as blanks.  Instead I prefer COUNTBLANK, which will count `""` as blank, so basically `=COUNTBLANK(C1)>0` means that C1 is blank or has `""`.

If you need to remove blank cells in a column, I would recommend filtering on the column for blanks, then selecting the resulting cells and pressing <kbd>Del</kbd>.  After which you can remove the filter.

Comment: The `=COUNTBLANK(C1)>0` really does the trick! the `ISBLANK()` wasn't  working for me. thks!

Comment: Any number > 0 evaluates to `TRUE` in the context of an `IF` statement, so you can just substitute `IF(COUNTBLANK(C1), .... )` no need for the `>0`, just to make things cleaner.

Comment: Here is a way to get a true empty blank as a formula result: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39351425/1903793

Comment: Use #N/A in cells instead of leaving them blank

Answer (score 28):

I wanted to add that there is another possibility - to use the function `na()`.

e.g. `=if(a2 = 5,"good",na());`

This will fill the cell with #N/A and if you chart the column, the data won't be graphed. I know it isn't "blank" as such, but it's another possibility if you have blank strings in your data and `""` is a valid option.

Also, `count(a:a)` will not count cells which have been set to n/a by doing this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a phenomenical (with a formula in it) blank cell to make an arithmetic/mathematical operation, all you have to do is use this formula:

```
=N(C1)
```

assuming C1 is a "blank" cell

Answer (score 2):

You could try this.

`=IF(A1=1,B1,TRIM(" "))`

If you put this formula in cell C1, then you could test if this cell is blank in another cells

`=ISBLANK(C1)`

You should see TRUE. I've tried on Microsoft Excel 2013.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Works in libreoffice calc as well!

Answer (score 1):

I've found this workaround seems to do the trick:

Modify your original formula:

```
=IF(A1=1,B1,"filler")
```

Then select the column, search and replace "filler" with nothing.  The cells you want to be blank/empty are actually empty and if you test with "ISBLANK" it will return TRUE.  Not the most elegant, but it's quick and it works.

Comment: This won't work, the find and replace will replace **filler** in the formula leaving the same problems as before.

Comment: I used the formula for the filler value, then pasted special to another column with values only, then did the replace with nothing. That finally got what I needed, where I was able to Ctrl+Arrow to jump to the next blank.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use conditional formatting if the IF Statement comes back false to change the font of the results cell to whatever color background is.  Yes, technically the cell isn't blank, but you won't be able to see it's contents.

Comment: It is possible to blank a cell with an if statement. While your solution is feasible it is not the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

This shall work (modification on above, workaround, not formula)

Modify your original formula:
=IF(A1=1,B1,"filler")

Put filter on spreadsheet, choose only "filler" in column B, highlight all the cells with "filler" in them, hit delete, remove filter

Comment: I somehow feel that it's not what OP wanted. It seems he wanted a formula. You say that this is not a formula, but still.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to show blank space:

```
=IF(AND((E2-D2)>0)=TRUE,E2-D2," ")
```

Inside `if` before first comma is condition then result and return value if `true` and last in value as blank if condition is `false`

Answer (score 0):

The formula in C1

```
=IF(A1=1,B1,"")
```

is either giving an answer of "" (which isn't treated as blank) or the contents of B1.

If you want the formula in D1 to show **TRUE** if C1 is "" and **FALSE** if C1 has something else in then use the formula

```
=IF(C2="",TRUE,FALSE)
```

instead of ISBLANK

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(AH38),AH38=""),"",IF(AI38=0,0,AH38/AI38))
```

Use the OR condition OR(ISBLANK(cell), cell="")

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is to set the value of NOT TRUE condition to make it show any error then you filter the errors with `IFNA()`.

Here is what your formula should look like `=ifna(IF(A1=1,B1,NA()))`

Here is a sheet that returns blanks from if condition :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15kWd7oPWQmGgYD_PLz9YpIldwnKWoXPHtHQAT3ulqVc/edit?usp=sharing

Nope ... that only works for Googlesheets ... not Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution returning N/A and using IFNA() to filter the cell output.
In your example, it will be something like:

```
=IFNA(IF(A1=1,B1,NA()))
```

Answer (score -2):

To Validate data in column A for Blanks

Step 1: Step 1: B1=isblank(A1)

Step 2: Drag the formula for the entire column say B1:B100; This returns Ture or False from B1 to B100 depending on the data in column A

Step 3: CTRL+A (Selct all),  CTRL+C (Copy All) , CRTL+V (Paste all as values)

Step4: Ctrl+F ; Find and replace function Find "False", Replace "**leave this blank field**" ; Find and Replace ALL

There you go Dude!

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using "", use 0. Then use conditional formating to color 0 to the backgrounds color, so that it appears blank.

Since blank cells and 0 will have the same behavior in most situations, this may solve the issue.

Comment: I don't think this is a satisfactory answer, as there will now be 0's in the raw spreadsheet data.  Exporting, copy/pasting, or any other task that deals with the data will not be correct with all those 0's.

Comment: it is bad idea because 0 has trouble with filtering by numbers. other way, 0 can be usual and correct value. then how to recognize between good 0 and "blank" 0 ?  I suggest you remove this answer :)

Answer (score -4):

This should should work:  =IF(A1=1, B1)

The 3rd argument stating the value of the cell if the condition is not met is optional.

Comment: Excel returns the value of first argument (FALSE) when condition evaluates to false and third argument does not exist. Unfortunately that does not seem to work.

Comment: Was sure I'd tested it -  but it doesn't replicate.   So you're right this answer is totally wrong.   Is it best if I delete it to save people's time?