# How to ignore blank cells while concatenating cells in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to concatenate multiple cell values in one cell as below:

```
Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D  Column E  Column F
Blank     Text 1    Text 2    Blank     Text 3
```

I am concatenating values from A to E

My formula is

```
A1&CHAR(10)&B1&CHAR(10)&C1&CHAR(10)&D1&CHAR(10)&E1
```

What I am getting in Column F is

```
Blank
Text 1
Text 2
Blank
Text 3
```

What I am looking for is

```
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
```

Can anyone help me with the right formula?

Answer (score 17):

I was just struggling with a similar issue caused by CONCATENATE() erroring out on blank cells. Instead, you can use TEXTJOIN([delimeter],[ignore blanks],[text1], [text2]...)

Like:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,A1:E1)
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to include a conditional to check whether the cell has a value or is empty. [If the cell is empty (via `ISBLANK()`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2452597/2118067), then return nothing; otherwise, return the value of the cell plus a carriage return.

```
IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",A3&CHAR(10))
```

So, for your five column formula (linebreaks added for readability):

```
CONCATENATE(
  IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1&CHAR(10)),
  IF(ISBLANK(B1),"",B1&CHAR(10)),
  IF(ISBLANK(C1),"",C1&CHAR(10)),
  IF(ISBLANK(D1),"",D1&CHAR(10)),
  IF(ISBLANK(E1),"",E1)
)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:E1)
```

The new [`TEXTJOIN` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) in *Excel 2019 and Office 365 versions* can accomplish this easier without all of the IF statements.

> The TEXTJOIN function combines the text from multiple ranges and/or
>   strings, and includes a delimiter you specify between each text value
>   that will be combined. If the delimiter is an empty text string, this
>   function will effectively concatenate the ranges.

In particular to the original question about **ignoring blanks**, setting the `ignore_empty` parameter to `TRUE` will automatically ignore blanks.

[image: excel table]

The `CHAR(10)` trick [Erica suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41367264/2105596) doesn't work with TEXTJOIN however. The formula `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:E1)` yields `Text 1,Text 2,Text 3` which requires an extra step to stack into a single column. Just copy the result, then paste below as values, then copy the values, then paste with transpose option.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula that will be useful if any of the cells in the data set contain more than one word (e.g. New York):

```
= CONCATENATE(
       IF(COUNTBLANK(B2)=1,"",B2&CHAR(10)&","),
       IF(COUNTBLANK(C2)=1,"",C2&CHAR(10)&","),
       IF(COUNTBLANK(D2)=1,"",D2&CHAR(10)&","),
       IF(COUNTBLANK(E2)=1,"",E2&CHAR(10)&","),
       IF(COUNTBLANK(F2)=1,"",F2&CHAR(10))
)
```

Notice that I have used the `COUNTBLANK()` argument in the formula because unlike `ISBLANK()`, `COUNTBLANK()` considers spaces (i.e.  ) as empty and returns 1. By applying the formula the words that are separated with space in each cell do not become comma delimited anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 365 subscription, this can be easily done using `TEXTJOIN()` function. Sample example below. Formula used is:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1)
```

the first parameter is `Delimiter` (in this case `,`)

the second parameter is "ignore_empty_set" - `TRUE` or `FALSE` (in this case, I have set it to `TRUE`)

Rest of the parameters are the list of cells that you want to join.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option: Empty cells will result in two linefeed characters in a row. Wrap a Substitute around your formula to remove them. Do that twice to take care of all possible occurrences.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1&CHAR(10)&B1&CHAR(10)&C1&CHAR(10)&D1&CHAR(10)&E1&CHAR(10)&F1,CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),CHAR(10)),CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),CHAR(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
= CONCATENATE(
       IF(COUNTBLANK(I2)=1,"",I2&CHAR(10)),
       IF(COUNTBLANK(J2)=1,"",","&J2&CHAR(10)),
       IF(COUNTBLANK(K2)=1,"",","&K2&CHAR(10)),
       IF(COUNTBLANK(L2)=1,"",","&L2&CHAR(10)),
       IF(COUNTBLANK(M2)=1,"",","&M2&CHAR(10)),
)
```